# Because of the places of the adverb 'now', is there the change of meaning?

Tags: grammar

Consider these examples:

1. There is no school in our country now that does not have a computer lab.
2. Now, there is no school in our country that does not have a computer lab.
3. There is no school in our country that now does not have a computer lab.
4. There is no school in our country that does not have a computer lab.

Because of the places of the adverb 'now', is there the change of meaning?

Comment: In the cited context I don't really see how there could be different meanings, so I can't see any possibility that these could be disambiguated by the placement of ***now***. It could go in several other positions besides the ones suggested by OP, but they all mean the same. In all cases we're simply dealing with the statement *There is no school in our country that does not have a computer lab* - and wherever you place ***now***, it just means *that statement is true **now*** (with the strong implication that it *wasn't* true at some point in the past).

Comment: Yes: in 1. and 3. "now" is a temporal adjunct and the meaning is the same. But in 2. "now" is a connective adjunct (notice the comma) used for introducing information that you think someone needs to know, as can be seen by the fact that you could say "Now, there is no school in our country that did not/will not have a computer lab", with both past and future meanings.

Answer (score 2):

The only one that has a different shade of meaning, or *can* have a different shade, is number two:

> Now, there is no school in our country that does not have a computer lab.

[**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/now) supplies this variation:

> **now** *adv*
>   8
>   b. Used to indicate a change of subject or to preface a remark: *Now, let's get down to work.*

So your #2 could be setting up further discourse:

> Now, there is no school in our country that does not have a computer lab. Yet the simple fact remains that the vast majority of students have their own computers. So the question I propose is whether spending money on computer labs is a good use of our schools' scarce resources.

Comment: Apart from [Now for Something Completely Different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Now_for_Something_Completely_Different), I can't actually think of a context where ***now*** placement significantly affects meaning (as opposed to a "delicate nuance"). Can you?

Comment: Because of the way you frame your question ("significantly affects" vs "delicate nuance") I would have to say no, except as noted in my answer. Nevertheless, nuances may be strong or "delicate" and significance may reside in the eye of the beholder. I consider that emphasis is a form of meaning, and placement of the adverb *can* change meaning because it may emphasize another part of the sentence.

Comment: @Robusto I agree. In 2. "now" is a connective adjunct (not a temporal one) used for introducing information that you think someone needs to know,

Comment: @Robusto: I quite agree "significance" is subjective. But I'd be inclined to see the two possibilities for closely-related ***then*** *(at that time, in that case)* as significantly different. Not that I can even think of an example where placement disambiguates *those* - the best I can come up with is *Are you coming then?* as a context where *only* the second sense could apply.